# i can not set Textarea empty

Tags: jquery

I am working with emoticon. I just want to set value on textarea after setting it empty. But it is not working.
My code is here,

```
$('.tooltiptext .emoticon').click(function() {
      $in = $(this);
      console.log($in);
      setTimeout(function() {
          var dataText = $("#text").val();
          $('#text').append(dataText + $.emoticons.replace($in.html()));
          var dataCode = $in.context.innerText;
          console.log(dataCode);
          var dataTextArea = $("textarea").val();
          console.log(dataTextArea + dataCode);
          //$('#textarea').html('');
          $('#textarea').empty();// it not working
          console.log($('#textarea').val());
          $('#textarea').append(dataTextArea + dataCode + ' ');

      }, 100);

  });

  $('textarea').on('keypress', function(e) {

      if (e.which == 32 || e.which == 8) {
          $in = $(this);
          setTimeout(function() {
              $("#text").html($.emoticons.replace($in.val()));
          }, 100);
      }

  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `val()`, not `text()`, `html()` or `empty()`, to clear the value of a `textarea`:

```
$('#textarea').val('');
```

Similarly, use it to set the value, not `append()`:

```
$('#textarea').val(dataTextArea + dataCode + ' ');
```

The same is also true of your `#text` element - assuming it's an `input` or `textarea`. A simplified version of your code would be this:

```
$('.tooltiptext .emoticon').click(function() {
    $in = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#text').val(function(i, v) {
            return v + $.emoticons.replace($in.html());
        });

        $('#textarea').val(function(i, v) {
            return v + $in.context.innerText + ' ';
        });
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Because you're setting the `value` property of the underlying element. `append()` is used to create an entirely new element in the DOM.